# Format JSON in Oracle (List Keys Once Followed By Values Sets)?

Tags: json, oracle

I'm looking to see if it is possible to format JSON in Oracle as a listing of the headers once followed by the listing of all the values sets.

Creating the following (on Oracle 19c):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (val1 varchar2(10), val2 varchar2(10), val3 varchar2(10));
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES ('1','2','3');
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES ('a','b','c');
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES ('1','b','3');
```

Running this query gives:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT (*) returning varchar2) AS JSON_VAR
FROM tbl1;
```

| JSON_VAR |
| --- |
| [{"VAL1":"1","VAL2":"2","VAL3":"3"},{"VAL1":"a","VAL2":"b","VAL3":"c"},{"VAL1":"1","VAL2":"b","VAL3":"3"}] |

Is it possible to format the output where we list the keys once then all the sets of values?  For example:

```json
{"keys" : ["VAL1", "VAL2", "VAL3"], "values" : [["1", "2", "3"],["a", "b", "c"],["1","b","c"]]}
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/p5ysfaGS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select json_object(
'keys' : ['VAL1', 'VAL2', 'VAL3'],
'values' : json_arrayagg(json_array(val1, val2, val3))) as js
from tbl1
```

Comment: Thank you. A quick follow-up, would it be possible to include null where null values are in the a field?  For example:  If you entered:  INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES ('4', null,'6'); the last set of values returns as ["4","6"], would it be possible to see ["4", null, "6"]?

Comment: @DBox [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Iaw4ar3m) Use `NULL ON NULL` as per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_ARRAY.html#GUID-46CDB3AF-5795-455B-85A8-764528CEC43B)